# Is there a way not to re-render some part of a React state?

Tags: reactjs

I have `messages` as state. This state can hold thousands of messages object. When new message comes in, a new message object will be merged to messages array of object. Thus, from what I understand, React will re-render everything to show updated messages view.

Is there a way not to re-render old messages, but only add to render the new message? Or what is the best way to achieve best performance for this case?

Comment: This optimization is already taken care by react using Virtual DOM. Real DOM is updated only by the part which has changed unless you mutate or provide new keys. If you want to explicitly avoid re-rendering you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method.

Comment: I recommend Mobx: https://medium.com/workday-engineering/react-performance-and-mobx-b038085ecb72

Comment: @tarzenchugh I think it's not happening on my case: https://imge.to/i/v3uBBj
You can see all other messages get re-rendered, and that's because the parent component MessageListView has updated the messages props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I have this kind of component tree:

```
<MessagesListView messages={messages} />

class MessagesListView extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    this.props.messages.map(message => {
      if (message.type === 'TEXT') return <MessageRow key={message.id} />
      else if (message.type === 'IMAGE') return <ImageRow key={message.id} />
      else if (message.type === 'AUDIO') return <VoiceRow key={message.id} />
    }
  }
}
```

Setting the children components of MessagesListView, i.e. MessageRow, ImageRow, and VoiceRow to PureComponent will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way not to re-render old messages, but only add to render the new message? Or what is the best way to achieve best performance for this case?

React already does this and is called [Reconcilliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

As long as you specify a `key` in your message component, React will retain old messages and only add new messages. Guaranteed that old messages never changes it's `props`, `state` and `ref`.

Comment: I think it's not happening on my case: https://imge.to/i/v3uBBj
You can see all other messages get re-rendered, and that's because the parent component MessageListView has updated the messages props.

Comment: @Inovramadani please see [this section](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys).

Answer (score 0):

React takes care of it,
Look into the profiler tool provided in react dev tools, it will give you better idea.

If you need to expicitily avoid re-rendering, use react.memo if you are using hooks(alternative for shouldComponentUpdate)

Comment: I think it's not happening on my case: https://imge.to/i/v3uBBj
You can see all other messages get re-rendered, and that's because the parent component MessageListView has updated the messages props.

Comment: Try making it a pure component.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you call setState the component re-renders and invoke `shouldComponentUpdate` there if you return true it will re-render and if false it will not, in that method you check for which state update this function is calling and filter it as per your requirement.